# Only add to select statement if logic is satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do something basically like this.

Pseudocode

```
DECLARE @logic BIT = 1

SELECT user_name, 
user_id,
if @logic = 1
(
(SELECT first_name + ' ' + last_name FROM users y
WHERE x.user_id = y.user_id) AS 'Full name',
)
birth_dte FROM x
```

The intent is that if a bit is set, it will add additional results to the select query.  I believe this is doable with dynamic SQL but I'd like to avoid that if another solution exists.

The 
CASE @logic WHEN 1 THEN...
method doesn't work here, because when @logic != 1, it will return a null column with no name.  I'd like it to simply not return that column at all, and just use the next one.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Edit: I could do "if @logic then select... ELSE select..." but my use case will end up using multiple different logic bit checks.

If I need to compare against @logic_1, @logic_2, @logic_3, @logic_4, @logic_5 I end up with a lot of repetition that I'd like to avoid.  I'm thinking this may not be possible to integrate right in the select fields, but I figured others might have some tricks I'm unaware of.

Comment: `case when exist`?

Comment: Why not move the `SELECT` into the `IF/ELSE` block, so you get one `SELECT` if it's true and a different one if it's false? Just because you'd have to keep them in sync?

Comment: As per your original question and your comments on the answers, there's no way to do this without dynamic SQL

Comment: @JoshPart Yeah it's sounding like it.  I appreciate all the help everyone.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question you want something like this:

```
 DECLARE @logic BIT = 1;

IF @logic = 1
    BEGIN
       SELECT user_name
           , user_id
           , first_name+' '+last_name AS 'Full name'
           , birth_dte
       FROM   x
            INNER JOIN users y ON x.user_id = y.user_id;
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN
       SELECT user_name
           , user_id
           , birth_dte
       FROM   x
            INNER JOIN users y ON x.user_id = y.user_id;
    END;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, he only wants the "Full name" field if the bit is set, otherwise he doesn't want it at all.

Comment: Adam is correct here,  If I don't have that bit set, I don't want that column returned at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below

```
DECLARE @logic BIT = 1

IF @logic = 1
BEGIN

SELECT user_name, 
user_id,
(SELECT first_name + ' ' + last_name FROM users y
WHERE x.user_id = y.user_id) AS 'Full name',
)
birth_dte
FROM x

END
ELSE 
BEGIN

SELECT user_name, 
    user_id,
    birth_dte
    FROM x

END
```

Comment: You could also replace the parenthetical `SELECT` in the `IF` block with an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I've considered this, and it would technically work, but there are multiple bits I'm checking against throughout, so there would be a lot of repetition when having to check against multiple iterations.

Comment: @Alo81 That is something you should maybe add/mention in your question

Comment: @whereisSQL you're right, I've added it to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @logic BIT = 1
       ,@Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @Sql = N' SELECT   [user_name]
                     , [user_id] '
        + CASE WHEN @logic = 1 THEN 
           N'     , first_name + '' '' + last_name AS Name ' ELSE N' ' END
        +  N' FROM [users] '

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
```